# @ConditionalOnProperty and "defaultValue": true

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a starter with some AOP logic. Please look at my autoconfiguration for it:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ConditionalOnProperty("simple-security.enabled")
public class AopAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    internal fun securedControllerMethodAspect() = SecuredControllerMethodAspect()
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `@ConditionalOnProperty("simple-security.enabled")` annotation.
Now, look at my `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`:

```json
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "simple-security.enabled",
      "type": "java.lang.Boolean",
      "description": "Whether to enable simple security.",
      "sourceType": "dev.d1s.security.properties.SimpleSecurityConfigurationProperties",
      "defaultValue": true
    }
  ]
}
```

So, my question is simple: why doesn't Spring take into account the `defaultValue` value for this property while calculating the condition?

Comment: What behaviour are you obtaining? Do you have simple-security.enable property defined in the application properties file?

Comment: Having `simple-security.enabled=true` in my `application.properties` will solve the issue. But I don't have `application.properties` in my starter at all.

Comment: Check the javadocs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html. "If the property is not contained in the Environment at all, the matchIfMissing() attribute is consulted. By default missing attributes do not match."  I thing you must use matchIfMissing = true for the that default value kicks in.

Comment: Hm, right, that will solve the issue. But is there any way to specify the **default** value for the property? If no, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` doesn't decide how spring will behave, rather it is to give the user a hint how to use your autoconfiguration. And in this case the hint is not accurate to what you have implemented.

If you want Spring to behave the same way when `simple-security.enabled` is not set and when it set to `true` you can make use of `matchIfMissing` param in the annoation `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

The above can be rewritten as follows:

```kotlin
@ConditionalOnProperty("simple-security.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
```

Alternatively, the default value of simple-security.enabled can be set in the class `dev.d1s.security.properties.SimpleSecurityConfigurationProperties`.

something like this:

```kotlin
/**
 * @property enabled Whether to enable simple security. Enabled by default. 
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "simple-security")
data class SimpleSecurityConfigurationProperties(
    var enabled: Boolean = true
)
```

P/s: I would suggest you let Spring generate the metadata instead of writing it manually. You can refer to this document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#appendix.configuration-metadata.annotation-processor

Comment: Thank you, @pringi's comment was the same as your answer.
Yeah, I heard about metadata auto generation, but I prefer the way of writing it manually tbh.

Comment: writing it manually may introduce a risk of the metadata not being up to date.
btw, I just edited the answer to add an alternative solution.

Comment: Saw your update, yeah, this is what I use already for default values. Thanks